# Understanding the one-way ANOVA effect size in scipy

Tags: anova, python, effect-size, scipy

I'm calculating F- and p-values using the [scipy.stats.f_oneway](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.f_oneway.html) ANOVA function and I'm having trouble interpreting the effect size f-values.

I'm getting numbers well above 100 in some cases, whereas from reading around it appears that $\eta^2$ is a score out of 1 (the proportion of the variance explained by the variable). So if the effect size statistic in `scipy.stats.f_oneway` is not $\eta^2$, what is it?

Comment: According to [this page](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.f_oneway.html), `scipy.stats.f_oneway` only returns an $F$ statistic and its $p$ value. **Neither** of those things is an effect size (as the term is normally conceived at least), though $F$ is certainly related to effect size. What makes you call it an effect size?

Comment: I'm not actually sure where I picked that up. I think reading somewhere that ANOVA tests usually return a p-value and an effect size and assuming that meant that the F-value here was an effect size. I'm not a statistician as you may have guessed so thanks for clarifying. I'll read up on the F-statistic then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One-way anova with effect size :)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-


import numpy as np
import scipy.special as special

def FPvalue( *args):
    """ Return F an p value

    """
    df_btwn, df_within = __degree_of_freedom_( *args)

    mss_btwn = __ss_between_( *args) / float( df_btwn)   
    mss_within = __ss_within_( *args) / float( df_within)

    F = mss_btwn / mss_within    
    P = special.fdtrc( df_btwn, df_within, F)

    return( F, P)

def EffectSize( *args):
    """ Return the eta squared as the effect size for ANOVA

    """    
    return( float( __ss_between_( *args) / __ss_total_( *args)))

def __concentrate_( *args):
    """ Concentrate input list-like arrays

    """
    v = list( map( np.asarray, args))
    vec = np.hstack( np.concatenate( v))
    return( vec)

def __ss_total_( *args):
    """ Return total of sum of square

    """
    vec = __concentrate_( *args)
    ss_total = sum( (vec - np.mean( vec)) **2)
    return( ss_total)

def __ss_between_( *args):
    """ Return between-subject sum of squares

    """    
    # grand mean
    grand_mean = np.mean( __concentrate_( *args))

    ss_btwn = 0
    for a in args:
        ss_btwn += ( len(a) * ( np.mean( a) - grand_mean) **2)

    return( ss_btwn)

def __ss_within_( *args):
    """Return within-subject sum of squares

    """
    return( __ss_total_( *args) - __ss_between_( *args))

def __degree_of_freedom_( *args):
    """Return degree of freedom

       Output-
              Between-subject dof, within-subject dof
    """   
    args = list( map( np.asarray, args))
    # number of groups minus 1
    df_btwn = len( args) - 1

    # total number of samples minus number of groups
    df_within = len( __concentrate_( *args)) - df_btwn - 1

    return( df_btwn, df_within)

if __name__ = "__main__":
    print( 'Sorry, you can not use it in this way.')
```

Comment: Nice. Have you submitted it to scipy?

Comment: @Jamie Not yet. I think this module could be improved to support command line input (e.g. loading data from files which I am learning to do). scipy has implemented this function except the calculation of effect size. I am new to Python and tyring to follow the coding style of scipy to keep the consistence :) Btw, thank you for the editing :-)